# Disabling/enabling a button based on multiple other controls using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of controls:

[image: form]

When a user clicks the Generate button, a function uses all of the values from the other controls to generate a string which is then put in the Tag text box.

All of the other controls can have a value of `null` or empty string.  The requirement is that if **ANY** of the controls have no user entered value then the Generate button is disabled.  Once **ALL** the controls have a valid value, then the Generate button is enabled.

What is the best way to perform this using Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be further optimized, but should get you started:

```
var pass = true;

$('select, input').each(function(){
    if ( ! ( $(this).val() || $(this).find(':selected').val() ) ) {
        $(this).focus();
        pass = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if (pass) {
    // run your generate function
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUg4Z/

**Note:** Don't use this: `if ( ! ( $(this).val() || $(this).find(':selected').val() ) )`.
It's just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Could you update your example with how I bind the control change events?

Comment: @link664 - you don't have to bind to the change events. Simply run that code when the user clicks your `generate` button.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted the question. I want to disable/enable the button based on whether there are valid values in the other controls - i.e. the user shouldn't be able to click the button if the values aren't all valid.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `$(this).fucus()` but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: @link664 - I don't like this approach. If you first select something from the `select` box then type something in the `input`, you can't click the `generate` button. You have to first blur away. Although you could overcome this by listening to `$('.tag')`'s keyup/keydown/keypress, that wouldn't take into account pasting text in, or dragging text in... You could then try to use the native `el.input` introduced in HTML5.....................................zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz. I think my solution is better.

Comment: I agree the forced blur isn't perfect, but in your scenario if the button is clicked and the data isn't valid, I don't know if setting the focus on the offending control is enough to let the user know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Generate button to be enabled as soon as the user presses a key, then you probably want to capture the keypress event on each input and the change event on each select box. The handlers could all point to one method that enables/disables the Generate button.

```
function updateGenerateButton() {
    if (isAnyInputEmpty()) {
        $("#generateButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#generateButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}

function isAnyInputEmpty() {
    var isEmpty = false;
    $("#input1, #input2, #select1, #select2").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
    });
    return isEmpty;
}

$("#input1, #input2").keypress(updateGenerateButton);
$("#select1, #select2").change(updateGenerateButton);
```

The above assumes that your input tags have "id" attributes like input1 and select2.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that all the form fields have a default value of the empty string.

```
$('selector_for_the_parent_form')
  .bind('focus blur click change', function(e){

    var
      $generate = $('selector_for_the_generate_button');

    $generate.removeAttr('disabled');

    $(this)
      .find('input[type=text], select')
        .each(function(index, elem){  
          if (!$(elem).val()) {
            $generate.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
        });

  });
```

Basically, whenever an event bubbles up to the form that might have affected whether the generate button ought to be displayed, test whether any inputs have empty values.  If any do, then disable the button.

Disclaimer: I have not tested the code above, just wrote it in one pass.

Comment: One quick bug with it is that the `focus` and `blur` events do not bubble on their own. JQuery might be doing some fancy stuff behind the scenes to *make* them bubble, or you could just change them to `focusin` and `focusout`, but it's just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I didn't know these didn't bubble.  I found a quirksmode article describing a workaround using event capturing and focusin/focusout, so I trolled through the jQuery source code.  If you search for "focusin", you'll find a section where they specifically apply the capturing-phase handler for compliant browsers and focusin for IE.  So it looks like jQuery will bubble these handlers even though the spec wouldn't.  Go jQuery!